# Jquery Diagonal Scrolling Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

If you look at this plugin: http://cubiq.org/infiniwall

You are able to scroll the div container in any direction, rather than just horizontal or vertical, and you can also change direction during a scroll without needing to remove your finger.

How can I accomplish this? I can't seem to find a plugin that allows it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post questions saying "do it for me". At SO, you should show what you've tried, then we can help you.

Comment: https://github.com/cubiq/infiniwall/blob/master/src/infiniwall.js

Comment: Well, as I usually do, if I had tried something I would have stated it. I also looked at the code but couldn't find exactly what piece of the script allowed it.

Comment: If you are asking how to make the scroll go a different direction, you can hijack the mousewheel and make it do anything you want with Javascript. It is the same idea behind making it zoom in and out on a map. You make a new event that causes it to scale the map instead of scroll the page, etc.

Comment: That's what I mean CoreyRS, you have to try something... Like changing the position of the div(overflow:hidden) contents when the mouse moves

Comment: **Quote OP**: _"I can't seem to find a plugin that allows it."_  ~  [You already did](http://cubiq.org/infiniwall).

Comment: @Sparky672 That is not exactly what the OP is looking for. They want to do the diagonal scrolling, not necessarily the infinite part, and that seems to be written for touch interfaces, which I'm not sure is what the OP is looking for

Comment: @JuanMendes, The OP says _so very little_ about what he actually wants, and my comment was based on such.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need `<div id="infiniwall">` with `var iw = new InfiniWall('#infiniwall');` Also note using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

https://github.com/cubiq/infiniwall/tree/master/demos/simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>InfiniWall - Indefinitely panning layer in Javascript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../../src/infiniwall.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#infiniwall {
    margin: 140px auto 0 auto;
    width: 510px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -140px;
    left: -170px;
    width: 850px;
    height: 700px;
    list-style: none;

    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
}

li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    height: 140px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0);
    display: block;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li img {
    position: absolute;
}

.spinner {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    left: -9999px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    background: url(images/loading.png) no-repeat;
}

.loading .spinner {
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.loading img {
    left: -9999px;
}

li span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 19px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <div id="infiniwall">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>

            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
var iw = new InfiniWall('#infiniwall');
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I did because it works (since you deleted your comment you asked why I pasted the working sample).  Check your error log.  I can't teach you to code.